# Script works in chrome but not in edge or other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have a script that works fine in Chrome but when it comes to edge or even on other browser it doesn't work

```js
$("#contactform").submit(function(e) {
  var checker = $('.hobby  :checkbox:checked').length;
  if (checker <= 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert("Please choose hobby");

  } else {
    var xSeconds = 1000; // 1 second
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#formholder').fadeOut('fast');
    }, xSeconds);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#resultcontent').fadeIn('fast');
    }, xSeconds);

  }
});
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a useless description. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to create a [mcve]

Comment: Also  `$('#formholder').fadeOut('fast',function() {
      $('#resultcontent').fadeIn(1000);
    });`

Comment: And `e.preventDefault();` is enough for a form

Comment: I suggest you to post a working example that can give us the detailed idea about the issue. If you are getting any error or warning message than let us know about that. It can help to narrow down the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the selector or the fade effect that doesn't work?

**If the selector doesn't work:**

If your checkboxes are coded `<input class="hobby" ...>` then your `'.hobby  :checkbox:checked'` selector won't work because it is looking for children of `input`.

Remove the spaces, and use `'.hobby:checkbox:checked'`

I would recommend avoiding jQuery's non-standard `:checkbox` selector, instead using `'input.hobby:checked'`.

**If the fade effect doesn't work:**

Assuming you want the result content to show in an iframe, then you need:

`<form target="resultframe" ... </form>
<iframe name="resultframe" id="resultcontent"></iframe>`

where `form target` matches `iframe name`.

If no iframe and no target, then the form submit will replace the current page. Unless the server takes over 1000ms to process the request, the current page's content will be replaced before the fadeOut gets a chance to start.